# How to traverse the template chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

Below is an example snippet of what I am working with.  Given an array of Contact data with sub array of Phones, then having a Polymer `<template  repeat='{{c,idx in contacts}}'>` and a nested    `<template  repeat='{{p,idx in c.phones}}'>`, I need to get the index of the selected phone to delete and the index of the containing contact.

Eric Bidelman showed me an easy way to get the idx of the selected model by using `sender.templateInstance.model.idx`  where idx is also exposed, but now I am trying to see if I can traverse up the template chain to get the senders parent template templateInstance.model.idx

See functions removeContact (this works as expected) and removePhone(this is where I need to traverse up the templateInstance chain to get parent idx)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test polymer</title>
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <polymer-element name="contact-list">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block; }

        .liveExample {
          padding: 1em;
          background-color: #EEEEDD;
          border: 1px solid #CCC;
          max-width: 655px; }

        .liveExample input {
          font-family: Arial; }

        .liveExample b {
          font-weight: bold; }

        .liveExample p {
          margin-top: 0.9em;
          margin-bottom: 0.9em; }

        .liveExample select[multiple] {
          width: 100%;
          height: 8em; }

        .liveExample h2 {
          margin-top: 0.4em;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 1.2em; }

        .liveExample TR {
          vertical-align: top; }

        .liveExample TABLE, .liveExample TD, .liveExample TH {
          padding: 0.2em;
          border-width: 0;
          margin: 0; }

        .liveExample TD A {
          font-size: 0.8em;
          text-decoration: none; }

        .liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR {
          border-bottom: 1px solid silver; }

        .liveExample td input {
          width: 8em; }

        li {
          list-style-type: disc;
          margin-left: 20px; }

        /*# sourceMappingURL=contact-list.css.map */

      </style>
      <div class='liveExample'>

        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <div id='contactsList'>
          <table class='contactsEditor'>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Phone numbers</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <template  repeat='{{c,idx in contacts}}'>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input value='{{idx}}' />
                  <input value='{{c.firstName}}' />
                  <div><a href='javascript:;' on-tap='{{removeContact}}'                    >Delete</a></div>
                </td>
                <td><input value='{{c.lastName}}' /></td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <template  repeat='{{p,idx in c.phones}}'>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input value='{{p.type}}' /></td>
                        <td><input value='{{p.number}}' /></td>
                        <td><a href='#' on-tap='{{removePhone}}'>Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <a href='#' on-tap='{{addPhone}}'>Add number</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <p>
          <button on-tap='{{addContact}}'>Add a contact</button>
          <button on-tap='{{save, enable: contacts().length > 0'}>Save to JSON</button>
        </p>

        <textarea value='lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>

      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        ready: function(){
          console.log("polymer ready");
          this.contacts = [
            { firstName: "Danny", lastName: "LaRusso", phones: [
              { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 121-2121" },
              { type: "Home", number: "(555) 123-4567"}]
            },
            { firstName: "Sensei", lastName: "Miyagi", phones: [
              { type: "Mobile", number: "(555) 444-2222" },
              { type: "Home", number: "(555) 999-1212"}]
            }
          ];
        },
        addContact: function(e, detail, sender){

        },
        addPhone: function(e, detail, sender){

        },
        removeContact: function(e, detail, sender){
          var contactIdx = parseInt(sender.templateInstance.model.idx)
          this.contacts.splice(contactIdx,1);

        },
        removePhone: function(e, detail, sender){
          //Doesnt work, need to get contact idx which is senders parent
          //template
          var contactIdx = parseInt(sender.templateInstance.parent.model.c.idx)
          var phoneIdx = parseInt(sender.templateInstance.model.idx)
          this.contacts[contactIdx].splice(phoneidx,1);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

</head>
<contact-list></contact-list>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Polymer, but it looks to me like the simplest approach would be to add an input for {{idx}} within the phone template, just like the one in the contact template. This would allow `removePhone` to get the proper contact in the same way that `removeContact` does.

Comment: Aw, the code should have had idx for phone number, that was a mistake.  But that does not solve the problem.  I can get the idx for phone number, but then I can't get the idx for contact was well.  If you look at the removePhone function and assume I return idx for phone then you can see that there is no way to also get the idx for contact at the same time.

Comment: I was thinking you would attach the contact's idx to the phone model, not the phone's idx. You would then use idx to get the  correct contact and filter that contact's phones to remove the deleted phone record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse back by accessing `.parentElement` attribute again and again (till `tr` node), it's kinda creepy but it's working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test polymer</title>
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <polymer-element name="contact-list">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
        .liveExample {
          padding: 1em;
          background-color: #EEEEDD;
          border: 1px solid #CCC;
          max-width: 655px;
        }
        .liveExample input {
          font-family: Arial;
        }
        .liveExample b {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        .liveExample p {
          margin-top: 0.9em;
          margin-bottom: 0.9em;
        }
        .liveExample select[multiple] {
          width: 100%;
          height: 8em;
        }
        .liveExample h2 {
          margin-top: 0.4em;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 1.2em;
        }
        .liveExample TR {
          vertical-align: top;
        }
        .liveExample TABLE,
        .liveExample TD,
        .liveExample TH {
          padding: 0.2em;
          border-width: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .liveExample TD A {
          font-size: 0.8em;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .liveExample table.contactsEditor > tbody > TR {
          border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
        }
        .liveExample td input {
          width: 8em;
        }
        li {
          list-style-type: disc;
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
        /*# sourceMappingURL=contact-list.css.map */
      </style>
      <div class='liveExample'>

        <h2>Contacts</h2>
        <div id='contactsList'>
          <table class='contactsEditor'>
            <tr>
              <th>First name</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>Phone numbers</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
              <template repeat='{{c,idx in contacts}}'>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input value='{{idx}}' />
                    <input value='{{c.firstName}}' />
                    <div><a href='javascript:;' on-tap='{{removeContact}}'>Delete</a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input value='{{c.lastName}}' />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        <template repeat='{{p in c.phones}}'>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <input value='{{p.type}}' />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <input value='{{p.number}}' />
                            </td>
                            <td><a href='#' on-tap='{{removePhone}}'>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </template>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href='#' on-tap='{{addPhone}}'>Add number</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <p>
          <button on-tap='{{addContact}}'>Add a contact</button>
          <button on-tap='{{save, enable: contacts().length > 0' }>Save to JSON</button>
        </p>

        <textarea value='lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'></textarea>

      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        ready: function() {
          console.log("polymer ready");
          this.contacts = [{
            firstName: "Danny",
            lastName: "LaRusso",
            phones: [{
              id: 0,
              type: "Mobile",
              
              number: "(555) 121-2121"
            }, {
              id: 1,
              type: "Home",
              number: "(555) 123-4567"
            }]
          }, {
            firstName: "Sensei",
            lastName: "Miyagi",
            phones: [{
              id: 2,
              type: "Mobile",
              number: "(555) 444-2222"
            }, {
              id: 3,
              type: "Home",
              number: "(555) 999-1212"
            }]
          }];
        },
        addContact: function(e, detail, sender) {

        },
        addPhone: function(e, detail, sender) {

        },
        removeContact: function(e, detail, sender) {
          var contactIdx = parseInt(sender.templateInstance.model.idx)
          this.contacts.splice(contactIdx, 1);

        },
        removePhone: function(e, detail, sender) {
          //Doesnt work, need to get contact idx which is senders parent
          //template
          var contactIdx = parseInt(sender.parentElement.parentElement.templateInstance.model.idx);
          var phoneId = parseInt(sender.templateInstance.model.p.id);
          this.contacts[contactIdx].phones = this.contacts[contactIdx].phones.filter(function(phone) {
                return phone.id != phoneId;
            });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

</head>
<contact-list></contact-list>

</html>
```

Comment: I will accept this as an answer it works but yeah I agree a little creepy.  Was hoping for a built in method that targets traversing polymer templates.

Comment: I think for now maybe its better just to use a custom attribute like data-idx and just pass the idx I want from html.  I originally did this,I modified question to demonstrate, but it just seemed like a lot of extra work for something that should be easy to get to.  Still for better solution.

Comment: Daniel Liewellyn has the answer see http://jsbin.com/piwetotego/1/edit?html,output and this for the full discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/polymer-dev/zkglHf1gAJs/0SYC6gAoP0wJ

Comment: @dan If you want a more reliable solution for this case, you have to have a contact_id field as part of phone model, this is far better than getting the parent id from the DOM, if you change the html structure your code will be broken, so keep the models isolated from the views.

Comment: @dan Yeah... He nailed it!